# Getting the footprint of LAS file in QGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, las, point-cloud, footprint

I can get the extent of a LAS file with:

```py
#Create a pointcloudlayer
lasfile = r"C:\GIS\data\testdata\22D054_684_39_7575.laz"
pc = QgsPointCloudLayer(uri=lasfile, baseName="test", providerLib="pdal")

#Create a polygon layer and add the pointcloudlayer extent
vl = QgsVectorLayer("Polygon?crs=epsg:3006&index=True", "extent", "memory")
f = QgsFeature()
f.setGeometry(QgsGeometry().fromRect(pc.extent()))
vl.dataProvider().addFeature(f)

QgsProject.instance().addMapLayers([pc, vl])
```

[image]

But how can I get the footprint of it? It does not have to be using PyQGIS.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a way. It involves reading a subset of lidar returns and creating a point layer from them, then concave hull the points.

```py
import numpy as np
#Load the las layer
lasfile = r"/home/bera/Desktop/GIStest/22D054_684_39_7575.laz"
laslayer = QgsPointCloudLayer(uri=lasfile, baseName="22D054_684_39_7575", providerLib="pdal")
laslayer.setCrs(QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem("epsg:3006"))
pcp = laslayer.dataProvider()

#Create a coordinate grid covering the entire extent of the las file
ex = pcp.extent()
xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax = ex.xMinimum(), ex.xMaximum(), ex.yMinimum(), ex.yMaximum()
spacing = 100 #This variable have a big impact on code performance. Start big and lower it
xcoords = np.append(np.arange(xmin, xmax, spacing), xmax)
ycoords = np.append(np.arange(ymin, ymax, spacing), ymax)
coordinates = np.array(np.meshgrid(xcoords, ycoords)).T.reshape(-1,2) #A 2D array of all x and y coordinates

#Sample lidar points at each coordinate and create a point layer of them
pointlayer = QgsVectorLayer("Point?crs=epsg:3006", "lidarsample", "memory") #Create a empty in memory vector layer
prov = pointlayer.dataProvider()

for coord in coordinates:
    x, y = coord
    poly = QgsGeometry(QgsPoint(x, y)).buffer(10, 3) #Create a polygon to sample in
    identified = pcp.identify(maxErrorInMapCoords=1, extentGeometry=poly, 
        extentZRange=QgsDoubleRange(0, 2000), pointsLimit=10)
    #identified is a list of dictionaries, one for each lidar point with the keys: 
    #   dict_keys(['Classification', 'ClassificationFlags', 'EdgeOfFlightLine', 'GpsTime', 
                 # 'Intensity', 'NumberOfReturns', 'PointSourceId', 'ReturnNumber', 
                 # 'ScanAngleRank', 'ScanDirectionFlag', 'ScannerChannel', 'UserData', 
                 #  'X', 'Y', 'Z'])
    
    for i in identified: #For each lidar point
        f = QgsFeature() #Create a new feature
        geom = QgsGeometry(QgsPoint(i["X"], i["Y"])) #A point geometry using the lidar x and y
        f.setGeometry(geom)
        prov.addFeature(f)
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(pointlayer)
```

I then concave hulled manually to get the alpha parameter right.

[image]

Comment: PDAL wrench available at https://github.com/PDAL/wrench/#boundary is being added to newer versions of QGIS which should support out-of-the-box boundary computation for datasets.